# Is this following code an example of the Buffon's Needle experiment?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0;
        double sum2 = 0;
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++) {
            int random = randomNum.nextInt(5);
            if (random == 1 || random == 3 || random==5) {
                sum++;
            }
            else {
                sum2++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(2*(sum2)/sum);
    }
}
```

This program is pretty self explanatory. I have a random number created every time the for loop runs. Then I have the program find if the number is equal to 1,3, or 5 and from that, the math is below.

**If this is not a valid experiment, could someone help me create one?**

Comment: A note on performance: is there a reason why you generate a new `Random` object in each iteration? It would be more performant to pull this variable out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, doesn't a random number have to be generated every time? Otherwise, we would be using only 1 number

Comment: No. `Random randomNum` is the random generator. calling `nextInt(...)` generates the (next) random value.

Comment: Oh, thanks will take that into note!

Comment: Here's a great [writeup on Buffon's Needle](http://datagenetics.com/blog/may42015/index.html).

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning as to why you think this is a model of Buffon's needle? It's clear you're having trouble with the code (after all, this program estimates 4/5 rather than pi, so is clearly not correct), but it's not clear where your misunderstanding is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not a "Buffon's Needle"-experiment. This code simply checks whether a random number in the given range is even. Buffon's Needle consists of two values: the coordinates of each end of the needle. And the result wouldn't be whether the needle lies within a given range, but whether it crosses one line out of a set of lines, or if it doesn't. A implementation of Buffon's Needle would require to generate two random values: the x-position of one end of the Needle and it's orientation. From these two values, the algorithm can determine whether the needle crosses a line or doesn't.

```
define createAndCheckNeedle:
    input: double[] linesX , double len
    output: bool

    //the position of x must lie in the range of floor-width
    double x = randomDouble(0 , linesX[length(linesX) - 1])
    //the orientation of the needle as rad
    double orientation = randomDouble(0 , PI * 2)

    //the position of the other orientation
    double x2 = x + cos(orientation) * len

    return contains(linesX , l -> min(x , x2) < l AND max(x , x2) > l
```

Comment: how would this look like in java?

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy come on, this shouldn't be too hard to translate into java, try it on your own.

Comment: alright, I understand it I was just asking to clear things up. Looking at the code now, I understand it! Just curious, however, what language is that?

Comment: @VishvakSeenichamy this is pseudocode. It's used to show the basic idea behind algorithms. This is not an actual implementation that could be compiled or interpreted by software

Answer (score 1):

This code does definitively not simulate [Buffon's needle experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle#Case_1:_Short_needle). Here is the proof:

- a) with [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-), you generate a random `int` between `0` (inclusive) and `bound` (exclusive) according to the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29). The possible outcomes with `bound = 5` are `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`.
- b) since we use a uniform distribution, each outcome has the same probability of `Pr(x = 0) = Pr(x = 1) = Pr(x = 2) = Pr(x = 3) = Pr(x = 4) = 1 / 5`.
- c) The event of `x = 1` and `x = 3` are mutually exclusive, thus `Pr(x = 1 ∪ x = 3) = Pr(x = 1) + Pr(x = 3) = 1 / 5 + 1 / 5 = 2 / 5`
- d) Using c), we can deduce that `E(sum)` is equal to `10000 * P(x = 1 ∪ x = 3) = 10000 * 2 / 5 = 4000`. Similarly one can show that `E(sum2) = 6000`.
- e) Using the information above, one can see that `E(2 * sum2 / sum) = 3` which is not equal to Pi = `3.14159...`.

As noted on the wiki page, you need two independent random variables for Buffon's needle experiment: one for the position, the other for the angle. I fear you have to redesign your wohle algorithm.

Comment: "The event of x = 1 and x = 3 are independent" - I'm sorry, what? They are clearly *mutually exclusive events*, hence they *cannot* be independent by definition. Also, you seem to use `|` as "Or", which is at the very least misleading, since in probability it's used as "given". As such `P(x = 1 | x = 3) = 0`, because if `x` is `3`, then it cannot possibly be `1`. I'm also skeptical on taking 6 paragraphs to explain that if you take a random number from 0 to 4 inclusive multiple times, then you'll have about 2/5 odd ones.

Comment: You are right on the exclusive part. Edited the answer. Regarding the syntax... I added a comment explaining the `|`. If there were LaTeX-style symbols, I would have added a `\cup`. For computer scientists, however, I figured `|` (as logical or) represents closest the semantics I meant (occurece of `x = 1 \cup x = 3`). Regarding the length: since this was not trivial for OP's writer, I took the approach of explaining it in detail.

Comment: Let's see how long it takes until someone complains about the uppercase u in the formula (`U∪`, the look [almost] the same). =)